# react-pdf generation is very slow in combination with umijs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro, react-pdf, umijs

I included **react-pdf** in a fresh umi project:

- PDF-Generation 150 Text-components took arround **311.44 ms without umi**
- Using umi: 7179.40 ms

**Every single element takes about 10X more in umi projects!**

**Code example I tried**

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Document, Page, pdf, Text, View } from "@react-pdf/renderer";

export default function App() {
  const pdfClickHandler = async () => {
    console.time("PDF generation took:");
    await pdf(
      <Document>
        <Page>
          <View>
            {Array.from(Array(150).keys()).map((key) => (
              <Text key={key}>text-element</Text>
            ))}
          </View>
        </Page>
      </Document>
    ).toBlob();
    console.timeEnd("PDF generation took:");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={pdfClickHandler}>
        Generate fast PDF (without ant-design-pro)
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**NOTE**: The following examples are `ant-design-pro` projects. BUT the error occurs in all `umi-js` projects.

- Fast version: https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-thunder-rybh7
- Slow version: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-leaf-hgk7c?file=/src/pages/user/login/index.tsx
  [image: Instructions slow version codesandbox]
- Slow version (GitHub): https://github.com/mleister97/ant-design-react-pdf-slow
- (Slow version is a fresh setup of ant-design-pro, just modified the "startup"-page)
  [image: fast version]
- (Make sure you open the Browser (:8000) Tab as the application is served on this port AND check directly the **browser's console**, not the codesandbox one)

**What is going on behind the scenes when the toBlob is beeing called?**

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221664/discussion-on-question-by-mleister-react-pdf-generation-is-very-slow-in-combinat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it:

1. `npm install assert browserify-zlib buffer process stream-browserify util`
2. modify 'plugin.config.ts' (umijs chainWebpack config)

```
export default (config: any, { webpack }: { webpack: any }) => {

  // Set alias
  config.resolve.alias.set('process', 'process/browser');
  config.resolve.alias.set('stream', 'stream-browserify');
  config.resolve.alias.set('zlib', 'browserify-zlib');

  // Set plugin
  config.plugin('record').use(webpack.ProvidePlugin, [{
        process: 'process/browser',
        Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
  }]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this issue comes from performance of *browserify process*, the **CRA** is fast for this test-code, because the configuration of Webpack on **CRA** used the new version of *browserify process* and it comes from `/node_modules/process/browser.js` but the **umijs** used the older version, the [`node-libs-browser`](https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser) that is **DEPRECATED** now and it comes from `/node_modules/node-libs-browser/process.js`.

I found it be adding break-points and track line after line and see when interpreter fall into `/node_modules/node-libs-browser/process.js`, it stocks for a long time which is not like it on `/node_modules/process/browser.js` and passes it as fast as can.

The `node-libs-browser` had a bad performance and the `umijs` should update its Webpack configuration to the latest versions. They still uses `webpack-dev-middleware` version *3.5.1*, it is now on vesion *4.x.x*.

The `umijs` has a great ability to get new configuration from developer by modifying `/config/config.ts` but its config docs is in Chinese language and still didn't have translated.

By these description I prefer to remove `umijs` from project. that is not a good solution but I think it is a wise decision